# matrix similarity over a field shows matrix similarity over subfield

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

$M_n(F)$ is set of all $n\times n$ matrices over field $F$. Suppose we have $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and invertible matrix $P\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $P^{-1}AP=B$. Show that an invertible matrix $Q\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ exists such $Q^{-1}AQ=B$.

I searched for the answer and found some answers to it: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57242/similar-matrices-and-field-extensions), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3179647/matrices-similarity-in-a-bigger-field-k-implies-matrices-similarity-in-the-sma), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972304/real-vs-complex-conjugate?noredirect=1&lq=1), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43838/how-does-extending-a-field-affect-matrix-similitude?noredirect=1&lq=1), etc. Some other answers suggested to use Jordan or rational canonical forms that I don't want to use (I'm not allowed). Answer 3 is comprehensible but is using determinant that I'm also not allowed to show a matrix is invertible using determinants (but I can use other theorems).
Answers in 2 and 4, both claim that we can write entries of $P$ using a basis of the vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. I can't understand this part. Entries of $P$ are in $\mathbb{C}$, so how can we claim that we can write them using elements in $\mathbb{R}$? Maybe there's something I can't understand.

Anyways, any new methods to proove the statement are appreciated. Also any explanations about those answers I linked.

Comment: $AX=XB$ is a linear equation in the entries of $X$ with coefficients in the reals. You solve it by elementary row operations, which never leave the reals.

Comment: @GerryMyerson In this question we have $AP=PB$ and entries of $A$ and $B$ are real numbers, but $P$ has complex numbers as coefficients. So how can we write entries of $P$ using real numbers? Where am I wrong?

Comment: What things are you allowed to use?

Comment: @user1551 _Hoffman_ and _Kunze_ book. Until chapter 3.5. (linear functionals).

Comment: Is this an exercise in Hoffman and Kunze? What is the exercise number?

Comment: You can't write a complex number as a real number. But you can replace each entry of $P$ by its real part (or by its imaginary part, if you prefer).

Comment: Do you understand, Mason?

Comment: I guess not. Too bad.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is not responding.